# how to check the string is UNICODE vb.net

Tags: vb.net, unicode, unicode-string

Is there any way to check if the string is UNICODE using VB.net.

Best Regards
inchikka

Comment: What string? Where are you getting it from?

Comment: In .Net, System.String is always unicode.  Are you trying to find out the encoding of a file or byte[]?

Comment: like this è, é, ñ, ò, ó  because when read write in VB.net it appear ¿½

Comment: Reading from _where_? How are you reading the string?

Comment: reading using this Dim objSR As StreamReader Dim objSW As StreamWriter  the text that I'm reading with è, é, ñ, ò, ó after writing it appear ¿½

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the file using the [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) that the file is written in.

It appears to be a non Unicode file that you are trying to read as Unicode, or possibly a different Unicode encoding than the default UTF-8 (could be UTF-16 for example).

`StreamWriter` has [several constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzyh741c.aspx) that the an `Encoding` as parameter.

Comment: @user709787 - a sample of what? MSDN has samples on the different links I have posted.

Comment: I found the link Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by validating each character in the string against the 128 characters in the ASCII table. If the character is not found there then it might be a unicode character.

Is that what you mean?